# rxjava :: zip function return an empty result

Tags: java, kotlin, rx-java

i am using Rxjava with  my app so i can fetching my data from tow different API server , to  combine the result using "zip" function and here is my code :
class1:-

```
var service = retrofit(1).create<cc>(cc::class.java)
var service1 = retrofit(0).create<cc>(cc::class.java)
var obs: io.reactivex.Observable<JSONResponse> = service.getsky()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

var result2: io.reactivex.Observable<List<get>> = service1.getTrends()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
var x:ArrayList<arrayitem> = ArrayList()


fun ini_conection() :ArrayList<arrayitem>{
    Observable.zip(obs, result2, BiFunction { 
        t1: JSONResponse, 
        t2: List<get> -> Pair(t1, t2) }).subscribe({

           for (i in 0..5) {
                x.add(arrayitem(gson.toJson(it.second.get(i).type)))
                x.add(arrayitem(gson.toJson(it.first.android?.get(i)?.title)))

            }

            for (s in x) {
                println(s)
            }


        })

        return x
}
```

when i call the result in ex: class 2 like this

```
    val h =Main_con()
            Log.e("hi i am work", h.ini_conection().toString())
```

the result i get was an empty array list

here also my arrayitem class:

```
data class arrayitem(var title: String)
```

by the way in this loop in ini_conection() function its print normaly the result that stored in x arraylist 
this is the loop:-

```
 for (s in x) {
     println(s)
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the result from async immediately. It must wait and ussualy only can be accessed by callback.

When you return x, you return array that initialize in:

```
var x:ArrayList<arrayitem> = ArrayList()
```

to get the x that filled with result, you can use interface or lambda to get your result.

here are examples using lambda:

```
fun ini_conection(onResult: ArrayList<arrayitem> -> Unit) {
    Observable.zip(obs, result2, BiFunction { 
        t1: JSONResponse, 
        t2: List<get> -> Pair(t1, t2) 
    }).subscribe({
        for (i in 0..5) {
            x.add(arrayitem(gson.toJson(it.second.get(i).type)))
            x.add(arrayitem(gson.toJson(it.first.android?.get(i)?.title)))
        } 

        for (s in x) {
            println(s)
        }
        onResult(x)
    })
```

}

And you can used it like this:

```
val h = Main_con()
h.ini_conection({res -> Log.e("Work", res.toString())})
```

Comment: excuse me sir  -> _)  what should i put here _ ??

Comment: and i didn't understand what u mean in the comment add this code in after line above

Comment: My mistake, _ in kotlin ussualy for variable that wont be used. But we need `type` not `variable` in lambda. So it is wrong to use _.

Answer (score 0):

you need to rethink your code. As @egon12 pointed out, you will first return empty `x` and then maybe make some operations on that array in the subscribe block.

There are to ways to solve that.

1. the ugly one, you can use `Observable.toBlocking()`, which will get you are of the `reactive code`.
2. Return `Observable<ArrayList<arrayitem>>` from `ini_conection()` and subscribe in somewhere else.

Normally the second approach would be better to use, as you could operate on observables and not block.